# MonoDroid OnBackPressed Not Working

Tags: android, xamarin.android

It is definitely firing because I can for only a moment see the dialog pop up, but then the screen backs out anyway.  How do I stop the back button from working?  My device is on Gingerbread and my Min SDK is 10.

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
    {

        base.OnBackPressed();

        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.myEquip);
        int cnt = tl.ChildCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = (TableRow)tl.GetChildAt(i);
            TextView tv = (TextView)tr.GetChildAt(0);

            if (tv.Text != "Equipment not found at current store")
            {
                Dialog d = inst2.showBuilder(this, "test", tv.Text);
                d.Show();
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `base.OnBackPressed()`, which is why you're still getting the default behavior. If you don't want the system to handle the back button, you shouldn't call that method. That said, in most cases you shouldn't be preventing the back button from working since that can be very weird for user experience. One example where it makes sense is if you were building a web browser: pressing back will go back to the previous page if there was one, and call `base.OnBackPressed()` if there are no more pages left.

Comment: That worked.  The only reason I am needing this functionality is so I can alert/stop the user from backing out before completing required fields.  If all is correct, they will still back out just fine.  Otherwise, a dialog appears asking them if they are sure they want to leave before they finish.